# How can i sent limited fields while updating form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

user.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Users = () => {
   const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    role: '',
    status: ''
});  ======>>>> I want to sent above fields only however while fetching user it fetchs extra fields that I don't want to send while  handle submit

const { name, email, phoneNumber, role, status } = user;
const handleChange = e => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};

const loadUser = async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/user/fetch/${id}`)
    setUser(res.data.response.info)
};

useEffect(() => {
    loadUser();
}, []);

 const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await Axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/user/${id}`, user)
};  ====>>> I want to sent limited user field here
 return (
    <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)} >
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor='name'>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" className="form-control" value={name || ''} onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
            </div>
 )

}
```

I am updating user it is working fine but what i get error it is fetching extra field in user state how can i handle limited fields to sent in handle submit while submitting form like I don't want extra fields to sent to backend. I want only fields which is in state

Comment: What are those extra fields you're talking about? Where are you fetching the User?

Comment: cant you do `await Axios.patch(`.../user/${id}`, { name, email, phoneNumber, role, status })` ?

Comment: Do you need the extra fields in your app at all? If not, strip them out when you fetch the user.

Comment: @prateek i have updated the code i am fetching user  in loadUser

Comment: since you have already destructured the fields above  something like this might work. ` `axios.patch('url', { name, status}) `

Comment: I have already stored data in the user which I want to sent still it is taking extra fields which are coming while fetching user like googleid, FBid which I don't want to send while submitting form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set the fields what you want to set and ignore the rest.

```
const loadUser = async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/user/fetch/${id}`);
    const _user = res.data.response.info;
    setUser({
       email: _user.email,
      //// rest,
    })

};
```

Or else just allowKeys which you want before patching

```
function allowKeys(obj, keysAllowed) {
  const newObj = {}

  for (const key in obj) {
    if (keysAllowed.includes[key]) {
      newObj[key] = obj[key]
    }
  }

  return newObj
}

// at the time of patching

const toBePatchedUser = allowKeys(user, ["email"... /** only allowed keys here */])
```